# Visual Studio Debugger: Skip over FaultExceptions being thrown

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, faultexception

I have my client calling a WCF Server I'm hosting locally, right now I'm debugging the client so on the server I'm purposely throwing a FaultException to see how the client would handle it.

The part that is annoying is that the debugger pauses on the line that throws the FaultException. How do I get it to **NOT** do that? I looked in Visual Studio's Options (Debugging) and don't see anything that resembles an option for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute on the method you wish the debugger to skip over.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the debugger to ignore certain exceptions by going to **"Debug -> Exceptions"** (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and unchecking **"user-unhandled"** for the exceptions or their namespace.

Disable either **System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1** For Typed FaultExceptions (FaultException< TDetail >) or **System.ServiceModel.FaultException** for both typed and untyped FaultExceptions.

Find both by searching for the words "Fault" with **"Find ..."** or by expending **"Common Language Runtime Exceptions-> System -> System.ServiceModel"**